# PHP version switch on centos 7

Tags: php, linux, server, centos7, vps

I have multiple version installed in my Linux centos vps server. when I check PHP version with the command

```
php -v
```

it gives me the result

```
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Apr 12 2018 19:02:01)
```

How to switch this default PHP version to " PHP 7.0.27"?

Comment: try `sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.0`

Comment: not worked " http://prntscr.com/kiwlm6 "

Comment: Provide a list with the full pathnames of all the installed PHP versions

Comment: input:  whereis php-config-----------------------------
output:     php-config: /usr/bin/php-config /usr/share/man/man1/php-config.1.gz